# How to read string line by line

Tags: c++

I want to make an application student manager. I want to user input information of a student just name and age, and then application will save it in a file. I can for my application save it, but how to read it? This is my code, It can read all information student in file but except first student. I don't know why?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

struct St
{
    string name;
    int age;
};

class StManager
{
    int n;
    St *st;
public:
    StManager()
    {
        n = 0;
        st = NULL;
    }
    void input();
    void output();
    void readfile();
    void writefile();
};

void StManager::input()
{
    cout << "How many students you want to input?: ";
    cin >> n;
    st = new St[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cout << "Input student #"<<i<<":"<<endl;
        cout << "Input name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, st[i].name);
        cout << "Input age: "; cin>>st[i].age;
        cout <<endl;
    }
}

void StManager::writefile()
{
    ofstream f;
    f.open("data", ios::out|ios::binary);
    f<<n;
    f<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        f<<st[i].name<<setw(5)<<st[i].age<<endl;
    f.close();
}

void StManager::readfile()
{
    ifstream f;
    f.open("data", ios::in|ios::binary);
    f >> n;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        getline(f, st[i].name);
        f>>st[i].age;
    }
    f.close();
}

void StManager::output()
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cout << endl << "student #"<<i<<endl;
        cout << "Name: " << st[i].name;
        cout << "\nAge: " << st[i].age;
    }
}

int main()
{
   StManager st;
   st.input();
   st.writefile();
   cout << "\nLoad file..."<<endl;
   st.readfile();
   st.output();
}
```

Comment: Please use a `std::vector` instead of that `new[]`. You have a memory leak to say the least. And look up "C++ getline skipping" because that's a problem here as well.

Comment: @chris: why is vector? Sorry I am new to C++, I don't understand that

Comment: To be honest, it should be taught before pointers as dynamic arrays in whatever book or resource you're using to learn. There are tons of examples out there on how to use `std::vector` and why it makes life so much better.

Comment: @chris: I am not study at school, I just study at home

Comment: And a good [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would be an extremely helpful asset to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Your `input()` function is fine. The problem is that you are calling the `readfile()` function -- which doesn't make sense since you've already loaded the input data once. Your `readfile()` does not call `ignore()`, which causing it to override the correct data that you previously had.